# Is there any alert available for cluster CPU utilization in ambari?

Tags: hadoop2, ambari

If yes then how to use that alert? And If it is not available then How to create an custom alert for getting cluster CPU utilization through ambari?

Comment: Which nodes do you want to be informed about CPU utilization, nodemanager nodes only, data nodes, or?

Comment: to master node.

Comment: The Hbase Master Node?

Comment: I want ambari to send email whenever the cluster CPU usage goes above a certain percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Ambari alerts are tied to services. Many services already have alerts for CPU utilization on nodes which run certain components. For instance Yarn has a `ResourceManager CPU Utilization` alert. This alert will be setup for any node running the YARN/RESOURCEMANAGER component. HBase has a similar alert `HBase Master CPU Utilization` which would be setup on nodes running HBASE/MASTER component.

It's not clear from your question what your cluster layout is nor how many nodes your cluster consists of. So I can't give you a definitive answer for your setup.

In general, if you had a component on every node in your cluster you could set up an alert for that component that monitors CPU Utilization. If you don't have a component on every node, then you would have to set up several such alerts across components to achieve what you want.

You can add or alter alerts via the Ambari UI by clicking the `Alerts` tab. In that view you can adjust alert notifications and alert settings by clicking the actions button and selecting the corresponding item from the drop down.

Comment: I have two Datanodes (no other component on them except datanode and nodemanagers) and a master node (a higher config machine) containing the YARN/HDFS and other master components. I want to set up an alert for the CPU utilization of the Datanodes, which as I've mentioned do not have any other components). Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I have specified in every detail of my cluster in the above comment. So could you now tell me how to create a Alert for the CPU usasge of the cluster.